# How do I connect to PostgreSQL in Sublime Text?

Tags: postgresql, sublimetext

I have tried all of the suggested plugins in package control, but I couldn't link Postgres to sublime. I am figuring out what exactly Connection is and the difference between Connection and System Build. Do we have a System Build for each query, table, or database?

I need to run my query from sublime text and create a connection between Postgres and sublime.

Comment: If you know how to create your query in a file and then run that file from the command line, you should be able to make a [build system](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/build_systems.html) relatively easily.

Comment: However, please keep in mind that Sublime Text is a programming *text editor*, not a be-all, end-all platform for all tasks related to programming. It may be possible to create live connections with databases for querying and analyzing results, but it probably won't be easy, and would involve significant amounts of Python programming, as well as knowledge of Sublime's API. There are other tools that are much more suited for this task than a tricked-out text editor.